# In the budget,fit tge budget and out of/dosen't fit my budget

Tags: word-usage

:)
Someone wants to rent a house. So he likes one and chooses to rent it. And the person who is renting it out says:

> Tenant: It costs just $200 per week.
>
> Renter: Oh! It is **out of/ dosen't fit** my budget.

So the person shows him another house.

> Tenant:It will cost just $120 per week.
>
> Renter: Great! That **fits/is in** my budget.

So in situation 1,what sounds natural:**out of/ dosen't fit**.

And in situation 2,what sounds natural:  **fits/is in**.

Comment: Both sound equally fine. It's purely a matter of personal choice which you use. (They do mean different things, however.)

Comment: It is “doesn’t” not dosen’t...

Answer (score 1):

Those are all normal, idiomatic ways of referring to what you can afford.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in OP's exact context the most common preposition would by *That's **within** my budget*. That's using a "container" metaphoric reference to "budget" (where the corresponding "too expensive" version would be ***outside*** my budget). By the same token *That **fits** my budget* is again a container metaphor, but that version isn't so common.

We can also use the "point on a linear scale" metaphoric form *(**beyond** my budget)*, which is often further restricted to "point on a **vertical** scale *(**over / above / under / below** my budget)*.

But we *don't* often use plain ***in*** in this context - probably because the usual "default" meaning of *That's **in** my budget* is *I **have made provision for that** in my budget*.